# fixed point and fourth order PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need some references about existence of solution for a fourth order PDE using fixed point method. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What type of fourth order pde?

Comment: degenerate parabolic fourth order PDE